# Using delphi application to ask question to ChatGpt

Tags: delphi, openai-api

I'm facing on ChatGpt to create an application using delphi 11, where the purpose is send data to AI then get a response related to it.

This is the code (but I get SSL protocol error on httpClient.Post as error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version)

I think that the problem is related to Indy 10 Components and its SSL.
Any suggestion?

```
function SendDataToChatGPT(data: TJSONObject): string;
var
  httpClient: TIdHTTP;
  requestURL: string;
  requestBody: TStringStream;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL ;
begin
  httpClient := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.create(httpClient) ;
    httpClient.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions :=[sslvTLSv1_2];

    requestURL := 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions';
    httpClient.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';
    httpClient.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization: Bearer myAPI_KEY'); //MyAPI_KEY is my personal token

    requestBody := TStringStream.Create(data.ToString, TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      Result := httpClient.Post(requestURL, requestBody);
    finally
      requestBody.Free;
    end;
  finally
    httpClient.Free;
  end;
end;


procedure TForm10.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  data: TJSONObject;
  dataArray: TJSONArray;
  dataItem: TJSONObject;
  response: string;
begin
  // Prepare your data as a JSON object
  data := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    data.AddPair('prompt', 'comment data and trend during interval date');
    data.AddPair('max_tokens', '50');

    // Create a JSON array to hold the data items
    dataArray := TJSONArray.Create;

    // Create a JSON object for each data item and add it to the array
    dataItem := TJSONObject.Create;
    dataItem.AddPair('Acid', 'Acetico');
    dataItem.AddPair('value', '10');
    dataItem.AddPair('data', '10/02/2003');
    dataArray.AddElement(dataItem);

    dataItem := TJSONObject.Create;
    dataItem.AddPair('Acid', 'Acetico');
    dataItem.AddPair('value', '11');
    dataItem.AddPair('data', '12/02/2003');
    dataArray.AddElement(dataItem);

    dataItem := TJSONObject.Create;
    dataItem.AddPair('Acid', 'Acetico');
    dataItem.AddPair('value', '8.5');
    dataItem.AddPair('data', '15/02/2003');
    dataArray.AddElement(dataItem);

    dataItem := TJSONObject.Create;
    dataItem.AddPair('Acid', 'Acetico');
    dataItem.AddPair('value', '10.7');
    dataItem.AddPair('data', '22/02/2003');
    dataArray.AddElement(dataItem);

    // Add the data array to the main data object
    data.AddPair('data', dataArray);

    // Send data to ChatGPT
    response := SendDataToChatGPT(data);

    // Process the response as needed
    Memo1.Lines.Text := response;
  finally
    data.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Hasn't this Q been asked many, many times before? Have you searched for "Delphi Indy SSL3_READ_BYTES tlsv1"?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Yes I did, but I didn't found a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching around, it seems that `https://api.openai.com` may require TLS 1.3 only, which `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` does not support, it can only do TLS 1.2 and lower.

To use TLS 1.3 in Indy, you will have to use [this WIP SSLIOHandler](https://github.com/indySockets/indy/pull/299) instead, or an alternative solution, such as [this SChannel SSLIOHandler](https://github.com/tothpaul/Delphi/tree/master/Indy.SChannel) <sup>1</sup>.

<sup>1</sup>: Note that TLS 1.3 is supported in SChannel only on Windows 11, Windows Server 2022, and later.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a ready-made library. It will be much more convenient and faster to work.
https://github.com/HemulGM/DelphiOpenAI

Or install it from the official GetIt package manager

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Remy Lebeau, the apporach with ICS components seems to work (at least at the login to the server)
I can say that becouse if I try to use a bad api key, the server returns

> {
> "error": {
> "message": "Incorrect API key provided: sk-a83ks****************************************jBgz. You can find
> your API key at [https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys."](https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys.%22),
> "type": "invalid_request_error",
> "param": null,
> "code": "invalid_api_key"
> } }

So, based on the following code, all works except the Json Data sent. In this case the server returns "httpPOST: Status# 400Bad Request"

```
procedure TForm10.HttpClientBeforeHeaderSend(Sender: TObject; const Method : String;Headers:TStrings);
begin
 // Headers.Clear;
  headers.Add('Authorization: Bearer ' + 'sk-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
  memo1.Lines.text:=Headers.Text;
end;

function TForm10.SendDataToChatGPT(data: TJSONObject): string;
var
  httpClient: TSSlHttpCli;
  requestURL: string;
  requestBody: TStringStream;
  SslContext:TSslContext;
begin
  httpClient := TSSlHttpCli.Create(nil);
  try
    SslContext:=TSslContext.Create(httpClient);
    SslContext.SslMinVersion := sslVerTLS1_2; // Set the minimum SSL/TLS version
    SslContext.SslMaxVersion := sslVerTLS1_3; // Set the maximum SSL/TLS version
    SslContext.SslVerifyPeer := False; // Set to True if you want to verify the server's certificate

    httpClient.SslContext := SslContext;
//    httpClient.SslContext.SslOptions:= [SslvTLSv1_3];

    requestURL := 'https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions';


   // httpClient.ContentType := 'application/json';
   // httpClient.RequestHeader_Add('Authorization: Bearer myAPI_KEY'); //MyAPI_KEY is my personal token

   //
    httpClient.OnBeforeHeaderSend := HttpClientBeforeHeaderSend;

    requestBody := TStringStream.Create(data.ToString, TEncoding.UTF8);
    try
      httpClient.URL := requestURL;
      httpClient.RcvdStream := TStringStream.Create('');
      httpClient.SendStream := requestBody;
      httpClient.Post;

      Result := TStringStream(httpClient.RcvdStream).DataString;
    finally
      requestBody.Free;
    end;
  finally
    httpClient.Free;
  end;

end;

procedure TForm10.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  data: TJSONObject;
  dataArray: TJSONArray;
  dataItem: TJSONObject;
  response: string;
begin
  // Prepare your data as a JSON object
  Memo1.Clear;
  data := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    data.AddPair('prompt', 'comment data and trend during interval date');
    data.AddPair('max_tokens', '50');


    // Create a JSON array to hold the data items
    dataArray := TJSONArray.Create;

    // Create a JSON object for each data item and add it to the array
    dataItem := TJSONObject.Create;
    dataItem.AddPair('Acid', 'Acetico');
    dataItem.AddPair('value', '10');
    dataItem.AddPair('date', '10/02/2003');
    dataArray.AddElement(dataItem);

    dataItem := TJSONObject.Create;
    dataItem.AddPair('Acid', 'Acetico');
    dataItem.AddPair('value', '11');
    dataItem.AddPair('date', '12/02/2003');
    dataArray.AddElement(dataItem);

    dataItem := TJSONObject.Create;
    dataItem.AddPair('Acid', 'Acetico');
    dataItem.AddPair('value', '8.5');
    dataItem.AddPair('date', '15/02/2003');
    dataArray.AddElement(dataItem);

    dataItem := TJSONObject.Create;
    dataItem.AddPair('Acid', 'Acetico');
    dataItem.AddPair('value', '10.7');
    dataItem.AddPair('date', '22/02/2003');
    dataArray.AddElement(dataItem);

    // Add the data array to the main data object
    data.AddPair('data', dataArray);

    // Send data to ChatGPT
    response := SendDataToChatGPT(data);

    // Process the response as needed
    Memo1.Lines.add(response);
  finally
    data.Free;
  end;
end;
```